# Can I use volatile on a collection?

Tags: java, enums, volatile, lazy-initialization

I have an enum and I think I can cache the result of `values()`.

```java
enum MyEnum {

    SOME;

    private static volatile Set<MyEnum> values_;

    public static Set<MyEnum> values_() {
        Set<MyEnum> result = values_;
        if (result == null) {
            values_ = result = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.allOf(MyEnum.class));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I tried the lazy initialization which permits duplicate initializations.

And the sonalint complains on `volatile Set<MyEnum>` part.

> SonaLint: Use thread-safe type; adding "volatile" is not enough to make this field thread-safe.

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3077

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: Can you use concurrent hashset instead entirely?

Comment: Your code is not strictly thread-safe.  Two threads could in principle both assign to values_.  Perhaps that does not matter in this case, but the tool can't know that.

Comment: By the way… Do you know that: All the constants of an enum class can be obtained by calling the implicit `public static T[] values()` method of that class. (from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html)) You seem to be recreating that built-in functionality.

Comment: @accessviolation So that I can put `@SuppressWarnings({"java:S3077"})` safely?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes I know that `values()` makes arrays everytime on requests.

Comment: @JinKwon - depends on your organization's standards as to what you should do.  As B. Bourque observes, why are you doing this anyway?

Comment: @accessviolation As commented, I want to avoid `values()` which creates an array everytime. Thanks.

Comment: @JinKwon JVMs are pretty good at eliminating this array alloc, for what its worth.

Comment: You're down the rabbit hole of premature optimization.  I suspect the laziness adds no value here.  If you need to cache (that's not obvious either), statically initialize (`static final Set<MyEnum> values = ...`) the field to the unmodifiable collection.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks. > "Why, sometimes I've believed as many as six impossible things before breakfast."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## `Set.of ( MyEnum.values() )`

Seems much simpler to just statically feed an array from `Enum#values()` into the [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E...)) method to create an unmodifiable set.

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/70m1iS).

```
enum Animal {
    DOG, CAT, BIRD ;

    public static final Set < Animal > values = Set.of ( Animal.values() ) ;  // A cached set of all enum objects.
}
```

Being `static` means this code runs when the class loads. So thread-safe. No need for `volatile`.

Being `final` means the reference variable cannot be changed to point to another set. The original set assigned will be the only set during the run of your app.

Being an [unmodifiable set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable), you can offer access directly to that static field rather than through a method.

The `Set.of` method is free to return an object of a concrete class of its choosing. Current or future implementations of Java may choose to use a class such as `EnumSet` for efficiency. The implementation of Java 12 utilized at Ideone.com uses the class `java.util.ImmutableCollections.SetN`, not that we really care.

Usage:

```
Set < Animal > values = Animal.values ;
```

> [DOG, BIRD, CAT]

You said:

> lazy initialization

No need to be lazy, to delay initialization, for such a trivial amount of work as making a `Set` from the `Enum.values()` array.

---

But I do not recommend this.

Your intention to cache this set seems to fall into the trap of [premature optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). See [this Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73314846/can-i-use-volatile-on-a-collection/73315039#comment129489436_73314846) by [Brian Goetz](https://www.linkedin.com/in/briangoetz).

Programmers are notoriously poor at intuiting bottlenecks. And modern JVMs are some of the most highly optimized software ever built.

I suggest just letting the client programmer call the usual `Enum#values()`.